# Can a character move a creature into an empty space that would require it to squeeze?

Tags: dnd-5e, forced-movement

[Page 192 of the Player's Handbook](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#SqueezingintoaSmallerSpace) has rules for squeezing:

> A creature can squeeze through a space that is large enough for a creature one size smaller than it. Thus, a Large creature can squeeze through a passage that’s only 5 feet wide. While squeezing through a space, a creature must spend 1 extra foot for every foot it moves there, and it has disadvantage on attack rolls and Dexterity saving throws. Attack rolls against the creature have advantage while it’s in the smaller space.

The Crusher feat from *Tasha's Cauldron of Everything* allows a character to move a creature it hits with an attack that deals bludgeoning damage 5 feet to an unoccupied space:

> [...] Once per turn, when you hit a creature with an attack that deals bludgeoning damage, you can move it 5 feet to an unoccupied space, provided the target is no more than one size larger than you. [...]

Could a character move a creature it hits 5 feet to a space that the creature could otherwise only occupy by squeezing, and thus inflict upon that creature all the disadvantages that entails?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no rule that says you *can't* use forced movement to push an enemy into a squeezing position, or into a bramble patch, or through a wall of fire, or even off a cliff. In the absence of a rule that says no, the default position is that you can.

Some DMs will give a character an extra save to see if they can catch the edge of a cliff or whatnot, but that's entirely on the DM to decide -- there is no rule that says those are required. As in real life, smart people do not fight on the edge of a cliff if they can help it. And since the results of being pushed into a tight space is much less than going off the side of a mountain, it's reasonable that doing this is just using good tactics and not restricted by the rules.

Back in 4th edition, there were a bunch of rules about what you can or can't force an enemy into, but that's not how 5e works.